# How to get suggested / autocomplete emails from gmail api?

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I used this api -
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
But this api only get your friends in contacts. I want to get suggested mail for example like the SS in below.

[image: Gmail screenshot]

**I will use in ios app.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gAuth.callAPI("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?start-index=1&max-results=2500&alt=json", withHttpMethod: httpMethod_GET, postParameterValues: nil)

max-results limit up to you.

or

var i=1;

gAuth.callAPI("[https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?start-index=\(i)&max-results=2500&alt=json](https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?start-index=%5C(i)&max-results=2500&alt=json)", withHttpMethod: httpMethod_GET, postParameterValues: nil)

every repeat you should add 25 to i -> i += 25;